# pushing values in a array javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this array of (x,y) values and I want to change the form in to(x:,y:). I tried to initialize data to rows and to an emplty array but it didnt work.

```
                var rows = new Array(
                Array(0,0),
                Array(90,90),
                Array(59,70),
                Array(65,77),
                Array(85,66)
                 );

            for (var i =0; i < rows.length; i++) {
           data.push({x: rows[i][0], y: rows[i][1]});
          }
```

how to initialize data array in order to have the wanted array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're only missing the declaration of the variable named `data`:

```
var data = [];
```

This JSFiddle works and outputs the right thing: http://jsfiddle.net/UraKr/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
var rows = [[0,0],
            [90,90],
            [59,70],
            [65,77],
            [85,66]];

var data = [];

for (var i =0, l = rows.length; i < l; i++) {
  data.push({x: rows[i][0], y: rows[i][1]});
}
```

If you wanted to directly modify rows:

```
var rows = [[0,0],
        [90,90],
        [59,70],
        [65,77],
        [85,66]];

for (var i =0, l = rows.length; i < l; i++) {
  rows[i] = {x: rows[i][0], y: rows[i][1]};
}
```

Comment: what is the intended output of data?